# Spring boot - MySQL - MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.product_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database, exception, spring-boot

After going through several threads similar to my problem with unsuccessful result, I am posting this. I get the error as in the heading. Below is my model file Product

Product.java
       package com.ms.Products;

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "product")
    public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ProductId")
    private String ProductId = null;

    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    private String ProductName = null;

    @Column(name = "ProductCategory")
    private String ProductCategory = null;

    @Column(name = "Price")
    private double Price = 0;

    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    private int Quantity = 0;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String productId, String productName, String prodcutCategory, double princeInEuros,
            int quantityAvailable) {
        this.ProductId = productId;
        this.ProductName = productName;
        this.ProductCategory = prodcutCategory;
        this.Price = princeInEuros;
        this.Quantity = quantityAvailable;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.ProductId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.ProductName = productName;
    }

    public String getProdcutCategory() {
        return ProductCategory;
    }

    public void setProdcutCategory(String prodcutCategory) {
        this.ProductCategory = prodcutCategory;
    }

    public double getPrinceInEuros() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrinceInEuros(double princeInEuros) {
        this.Price = princeInEuros;
    }

    public int getQuantityAvailable() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantityAvailable(int quantityAvailable) {
        this.Quantity = quantityAvailable;
    }

}

Database schema

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_products |
+--------------------+
| category           |
| product            |
| users              |
+--------------------
```

+

```
My product table

mysql> select * from product;
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| ProductId | ProductName | ProductCategory | Price | Quantity |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+
| 1         | Cheese      | L               |  1.65 |       25 |
| 2         | Milk        | L               |   0.5 |       55 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

my application.properties

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Products
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=sj
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Please any help me with an idea on what am i missing here or what i need to do here?

I get this error while trying to add or view. M controller code

```
PRoductController.java

@Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/allProducts")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/addProduct")
    public String addProduct(Product productFromView) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductId("3");
        product.setProductName("Salt");
        product.setProdcutCategory("L");
        product.setPrinceInEuros(0.65); 
        product.setQuantityAvailable(20);
        productService.addProduct(product);
        return "Product Added";
    }
```

ProductService.java

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        productDao.findAll().forEach(products::add);
        return products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productDao.save(product);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to do 'add' and 'view' operation

Comment: the db schema is ProductId but your function call productId ..check for proper case